# Variable queda null después de tratar de llenarla con for

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencsv

Estoy recibiendo datos desde un csv con *OPENCSV*, los recorro con doble ciclo **FOR** y los muestro correctamente, pero al querer guardar los datos que muestro, la variable `aux[][]` queda null y no logro comprender porqué.

Para revisar que se mostraran correctamente, coloqué un par de `System.out.print()` con las variables `i` y `j` para asegurarme, y efectivamente realizan el aumento, por lo que quedo en blanco ya que la consola solo muestra que existe el error "`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "aux" is null`".

```
    List<String[]> bps = csvr.readAll();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    String[][] aux = null;
        
    for(String[] linea : bps) {
        System.out.print(" | i: " + i + " | ");
        for(String celda : linea) {
            System.out.print(" | j: " + j + " | ");
            System.out.print(celda + "\t");
            aux[i][j] = celda;
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
```

¿me estará faltando alguna declaración?

Si quito o comento la variable aux, el código se ejecuta correctamente, mostrando lo siguiente:

```
| i: 0 |  | j: 0 | IdCliente     | j: 1 | NIFnumber  | j: 2 | Nombre     | j: 3 | Email  | j: 4 | Fono   | j: 5 | Direccion  | j: 6 | Ciudad     | j: 7 | IdContacto     | j: 8 | NombreContacto     | j: 9 | EmailContacto  | j: 10 | FonoContacto  | j: 11 | DireccionContacto     | j: 12 | DireccionFacturacion  | j: 13 | CiudadFacturacion     | j: 14 | EstadoRegion  | j: 15 | CodigoPostal  | j: 16 | Pais  | j: 17 | FormaPago     | j: 18 | ListaPrecios  | j: 19 | CuentaBanco   | j: 20 | NombreBanco   | j: 21 | PaisBanco     | j: 22 | CodigoBanco   | j: 23 | CodigoSwift  
| i: 1 |  | j: 0 | 12345678-0C   | j: 1 | 12345678-0     | j: 2 | Paterno Materno Nombres    | j: 3 | correo1@mail.cl    | j: 4 | 56912345678    | j: 5 | Direccion personal     | j: 6 | Nombre de ciudad   | j: 7 | 1-9    | j: 8 | Paterno2 Materno2 Nombres2     | j: 9 | correo2@mail.cl    | j: 10 | 56987654321   | j: 11 | Direccion 2   | j: 12 | Direccion 3   | j: 13 | Ciudad 2  | j: 14 | Estado 1  | j: 15 | 5550000   | j: 16 | Chile     | j: 17 | 1     | j: 18 | 1     | j: 19 | 87600012345   | j: 20 | Banco 1   | j: 21 | Chile     | j: 22 | 037   | j: 23 | BSCHCLRM 
| i: 2 |  | j: 0 | 4-3C  | j: 1 | 4-3    | j: 2 | Cliente 4 de prueba    | j: 3 | cliente4@dimarsa.cl    | j: 4 | 56-65-2345678  | j: 5 | Direccion 4 de prueba  | j: 6 | PUERTO VARAS  
| i: 3 |  | j: 0 | 5-1C  | j: 1 | 5-1    | j: 2 | cliente 5 de prueba    | j: 3 | cliente5@dimarsa.cl    | j: 4 | 56-65-2456789  | j: 5 | direccion 5 de prueba  | j: 6 | PUERTO VARAS   | j: 7 | 3-3    | j: 8 | Nombre completo contacto 3     | j: 9 | notiene@sinserver.cl   | j: 10 | 988776655     | j: 11 | Direccion 3 de contacto  
| i: 4 |  | j: 0 | 6-KC  | j: 1 | 6-K    | j: 2 | Cliente 6 de prueba    | j: 3 | cliente6@dimarsa.cl    | j: 4 | 56-65-2987654  | j: 5 | Direccion 6 de prueba  | j: 6 | PUERTO MONTT   | j: 7 | 4-4    | j: 8 | Nombre completo contacto 4     | j: 9 | notiene@sinserver.cl   | j: 10 | 955667788     | j: 11 | Direccion 4 de contacto   | j: 12 | Direccion DESPACHO    | j: 13 | Ciudad DESPACHO   | j: 14 | Region DESPACHO   | j: 15 | 5550000   | j: 16 | Chile
```

El CSV se ve algo así:

```
12345678-0C;12345678-0;Paterno Materno Nombres;correo1@mail.cl;56912345678;Direccion personal;Nombre de ciudad;1-9;Paterno2 Materno2 Nombres2;correo2@mail.cl;56987654321;Direccion 2;Direccion 3;Ciudad 2;Estado 1;5550000;Chile;1;1;87600012345;Banco 1;Chile;037;BSCHCLRM
4-3C;4-3;Cliente 4 de prueba;cliente4@dimarsa.cl;56-65-2345678;Direccion 4 de prueba;PUERTO VARAS
5-1C;5-1;cliente 5 de prueba;cliente5@dimarsa.cl;56-65-2456789;direccion 5 de prueba;PUERTO VARAS;3-3;Nombre completo contacto 3;notiene@sinserver.cl;988776655;Direccion 3 de contacto
6-KC;6-K;Cliente 6 de prueba;cliente6@dimarsa.cl;56-65-2987654;Direccion 6 de prueba;PUERTO MONTT;4-4;Nombre completo contacto 4;notiene@sinserver.cl;955667788;Direccion 4 de contacto;Direccion DESPACHO;Ciudad DESPACHO;Region DESPACHO;5550000;Chile
```

Comment: El arreglo lo estás declarando nulo. Cuando declaras un arreglo debes especificar su tamaño para inicializarlo. Si no lo inicializas será siempre null. Ej: String[][] aux = new String[4][5]; para un arreglo de 4 filas y 5 columnas. Si no sabes la cantidad de datos mejor usa una lista de listas.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Probaré con las listas como dices, ya que el CSV que uso es solo un ejemplo y no sé cuántos datos realmente se recibirán, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar un fragmento del csv para darte un ejemplo de como puedes obtener el arreglo usando streams?

Comment: Edita tu pregúnta y adjúntalo.  No lo coloques en comentarios que pierde todo el formato.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Editado.

Comment: Disculpa la demora, todo el código de los `for` para crear el array se puede resumir a una sola línea `String[][] aux = bps.stream().toArray(String[][]::new );`. Si quieres imprimirlo para ver como te queda usa   `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString( aux ));`

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Muchas Gracias! estaré probando lo que me has enseñado.

Comment: Solo hacer una observación. Con la conversión a array simplemente estás agregando de cierta manera *"azucar sintáctico"* a la forma a la que accedes a `bps` pero no veo necesario hacer la conversión. Por ejemplo, con `bps`, para acceder al elemento `(1,5)` usarías `bps.get(1)[5]` mientras que convertido a array sería `aux[1][5]`. No se si vale la pena por esa simple diferencia hacer toda esa conversión, pero bueno, es cuestión de gustos.